# Self-Learning Epsilon-Delta Proofs (Suggestions)

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I'm self-learning analysis and everything seems fine so far actually, but I'm not feeling confident about epsilon-delta proofs. Being more accurate, I can easily understand and replicate the proofs I read, however, I can't come up with the "right" idea. As I'm self learning it, a list of exercises with answers would be helpful. If possible, I would like to start by doing exercises involving $n_0$ and $\epsilon$, finding the limit of sequences and series. The more general the better, because I had a hard time trying to prove results like: summable sequence $\iff$ series is absolutely convergent. I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some exercises on this in chapter one of "Calculus" by Spivak, in particular the exercises 19 to 23 are specifically about methods of epsilon/delta proof.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Lots of practice. Helps to work with someone.

Comment: Paul's Online Math Notes , with worked exercices. You ma also have a look at OpenStax ( free) Calculus textbook.

Answer (score -1):

The $\epsilon -\delta $ proofs use topology in disguise. Then they would be easier to handle if you know a bit of topology before to try an $\epsilon -\delta $ proof (anyway you can handle $\epsilon -\delta $ proofs without a knowledge of topology, however in my experience topology was the key to fully master these kind of proofs).

The point is that the topological notions of limit point and continuity are highly visual so you can see almost all the steps of the proof in your head before to write it. However without this vision is harder to write out an $\epsilon -\delta $ proof just using blind attempts.

By the other hand in my experience the $\epsilon -\delta $ proofs are the most difficult thing you will study in your degree, so once you are used to them (and for this matter topology is very useful as a visual tool) you will have little more complications studying mathematics.

Anyway you will need effort and a lot of practice to get over this bump. Good luck!

Comment: Epsilon-delta is the *hardest*? Analysis can happily get far “worse”, even at undergraduate

Comment: @FShrike in my experience is the hardest thing I had learned. In general, in any degree, the more basics things that one study in the first two years are the hardest things to learn. Once someone is used to the basic notions of some degree everything becomes way easier

Comment: You are truly remarkable. You think epsilon-delta proofs were harder to learn than say,  Galois theory?

Comment: @John of course, at least in my experience. As I said: the hardest things to learn in a degree are the first ones, not the later ones.